# Why does the visibility "gone" for button not work with scrollviews?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-linearlayout, android-view

I have a layout like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <-- A relative layout that contains a lot of edit text fields and a few text views at the bottom that cover up the screen-->

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="something"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and what i want to do is just achieve the effect that when the keyboard pops up from tapping on any `EditView` inside the `ScrollView`, the button at the bottom should NOT cover up any text views, because it is in the `gone` state. but right now, whenever i tap on any of the `EditText` fields, it seems to be covering up some of the text views that i have.

why is the screen rendered such that it designates space for the `gone` button i have at the bottom?

Comment: can u post the GUI representation of what issue you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the activity tag in your manifest.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Comment: doesn't work, the keyboard just hides the button on the bottom :/